# Haskell: Number of matches between two lists of ints?

Tags: haskell, count, numbers, match

Say I have two lists of integers:

```
4 12 24 26 35 41

42 24 4 36 2 26
```

There are 3 matches between the two lists.

How do I count the number of matches between any two list in Haskell?

Thanks.

Comment: If the `2` in the second list was another `4`, would that make 4 matches? And if the `12` in the first list was also another `4`, would that make 6 matches, 4 matches, or still just 3 matches?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, the lists don't contain any duplicated. I've got my answer now, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need to take care of multiple elements, the easy way is to calculate the length of the intersection

```
import Data.List

matches :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
matches xs ys = length (intersect xs ys)
```

Somewhat more efficient is using `Set`s as intermediate structures, if you also have an `Ord` instance:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

matches :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
matches xs ys = S.size (S.intersection (S.fromList xs) (S.fromList ys))
```

If you need to take care of repetitions, using a `Map` counting the number of occurrences for each element would be a not too difficult modification.

Comment: Nice demonstration of Set; Haskellers really should try to use appropriate containers other than List more often.

Comment: it could be a multiset.

Answer (score 5):

It's going to be quite painful with lists as you've going to need to go through them all the pairs.  Something like this prints out the right answer by forming all pairs where they are equal and then counting the size.

```
let xs = [1,2,3,4]
let ys = [1,2,3,4]
length [x | x <- xs, y <- ys, x == y]
```

It's quite awkward to do it this way from a performance point of view.  For large lists you're better off using a set as you can test membership quicker (typically O(lg N), sometimes O(1) ) than you can with a list (O(N)).

Answer (score 2):

The function `intersect` from `Data.List` returns the intersection between two given lists.

```
import Data.List (intersect)

numberOfIntersections :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int
numberOfIntersections xs ys = length $ intersect xs ys

main = do
    print $ numberOfIntersections [4, 12, 24, 26, 35, 41] [42, 24, 4, 36, 2, 26]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution using only lists, which is not so slow as `Data.List.intersect`, you can use this:

```
intersectSorted [] _ = []
intersectSorted _ [] = []
intersectSorted (x : xs) (y : ys) = case compare x y of
  LT -> intersectSorted xs (y : ys)
  EQ -> x : intersectSorted xs ys
  GT -> intersectSorted (x : xs) ys

intersect a b = intersectSorted (sort a) (sort b)
```